# Find the smallest possible value and the largest possible value for the interquartile range.

Tags: statistics

The weights of 220 sausages are summarized in the following table.

```
Weight (grams)  Cumulative frequency
   <20             0
   <30             20
   <40             50
   <45             100
   <50             160
   <60             210
   <70             220
```

What is the smallest possible value and the largest possible value for the interquartile range?

[Question 4 is where the question was extracted from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HajH.png)

Comment: Welcome to the forum! You might want to take a look around at some other posts: users generally will post their problems, explain what they have tried and then pose their questions; otherwise it might come across as you simply asking the internet to do your homework.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is closed for being unclear. It seems very to me. We are given a data set with only partial information (bins and frequencies). We thus cannot say for sure what the IQR is; we can only give a range of values that it could be given the partial information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we were to assume that each sausage has the minimum weight that entitles it to its bin then the $55$th and $56$th sausage would both have a weight of $40$ grams (and $Q_1$ would be $40$). If we were to assume that each sausage has the maximum weight that entitles it to a bin then these sausages would both have a weight of $45$ grams (treating the weight as continuous). Thus, without these assumptions, $40 < Q_1 < 45$.

Similarly, $50 < Q_3 < 60$.

The minimum value of the $IQR$, then must then be $50 - 45 = 5$ while the maximum value must be $60-40=20$.

Note that when dealing with grouped statistics we often assume that the items in the bin take on the bin's mid-point (though we could make other choices such as interpolation based on the overall distribution). On the other hand, I think that grouped data techniques are a bit of a relic from the days when people did statistics manually that is becoming less important as a computation-saving device and that is only really used in the real world when dealing with imprecision.

Comment: 40<Q1<45 if this is the case then should not it mean that neither 40 nor 45 are included in the interval ?

Comment: If we are treating the weight as continuous then any weight that is arbitrarily close to 45 would be included in the bin so long as it is less than 45 and greater than 40. If we were dealing with discrete data then we would use the largest and smallest values that are eligible for a given bin.

Comment: So for any continuous data both the upper and lower limits are available to that bin. But this does not apply to discrete random data like number of people etc.Am I right ?

Comment: Pretty much. This issue sometimes also comes into play when we want to calculate the mid-point of a bin.

Comment: Thank you very much. You might have saved my finals mister :)